# Upper bound of mutual information in a Markov chain

Tags: probability, information-theory, information-geometry

Consider binary random variables $X$ and $V$ with marginal distributions $p$ and $\pi$ respectively and also the conditional distribution $p(X=x\mid V=v)=q(x\mid v)$, where $x\in\{-b,b\}$ and $v\in\{-1,1\}$.

I am looking for a random transformation (channel) of $X$, with output $Z$, which maximizes the mutual information $I(X; Z)$ while keeping $I(V;Z)\leq \epsilon$.

Comment: Is $Z$ also a binary random variable?

Comment: To make the problem easy, we can assume that $Z$ is also binary. Hope that helps